# Problemas con datagridview Checkbox

Tags: vb.net

Tengo un `DataGridView` con las columnas

- Enfermedad
- AbueloP
- AbueloM
- Padre
- Madre
- Tios
- Hermanos
- Primos

Agrego a la primera columna las enfermedades a través de:

```
 objeto.Rows.Add("Hipertensión Arterial")
 objeto.Rows.Add("Obesidad")
 objeto.Rows.Add("Cardiopatía")
 objeto.Rows.Add("Epilepsia")
 objeto.Rows.Add("Artritis Reumatoide")
 objeto.Rows.Add("Cancer")
 objeto.Rows.Add("Malformaciones Congénitas")
 objeto.Rows.Add("Enfermedades Mentales")
 objeto.Rows.Add("Dislipidemia")
 objeto.Rows.Add("Diabetes")
 objeto.Rows.Add("Drogas/Alcohol")
  objeto.Rows.Add("Asma Bronquial")
```

El problema surge que lo quiero Insertar en la base de datos  cada vez que termine de contar las Columnas que se seleccionaron en esa fila, pero me imprime valores que no deseo. Es decir, cuando acaba el recorrido en las columnas no incremente el valor de los renglones

```
 For Renglones As Integer = 0 To dtg_antecedentesH.RowCount - 1
        For Columnas As Integer = 0 To dtg_antecedentesH.ColumnCount - 1
            If (Columnas > 0) Then
                'MsgBox(Renglones)

                If (Convert.ToBoolean(dtg_antecedentesH.Item(Columnas, Renglones).Value)) Then

                    arregloFamiliarEnf(Columnas) = "si"
                    MsgBox(arregloFamiliarEnf(Columnas))
                    arregloEnfermedad = dtg_antecedentesH.Item(0, Renglones).Value
                    MsgBox(arregloEnfermedad)
                    Continue For


                End If

            End If
        Next Columnas

        Insertar_ExpedienteEnfermedades(arregloFamiliarEnf, arregloEnfermedad)

    Next Renglones
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Podrias ser mas claro con tu problema? ayudate de ejemplos si puedes